# MySQL, perform a query that selects and filters the results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with this structure:

```
id          seller          class           ref             color       pricekg

1           manta           apple           apple-red       red         0.147
2           manta           pear            pear-green      green       0.122
3           poma            apple           apple-red       red         0.111
4           arnie           melon           melon-green     green       0.889
5           pinas           pineapple       pinneaple-brown brown       0.890
6           gordon          apple           apple-red       red         0.135
```

I would need to get some fruits from some sellers, with some preferences.

My first objective is to know who sells what im looking for, and after I know that, pick the best one.

When I do the first query I get this:

Query ->

```
SELECT *  
FROM  `fruits`   
WHERE  `seller`  
IN ("manta",  "poma",  "pinas",  "gordon")  
AND  `class` IN ("apple",  "pineapple")  
ORDER BY id
```

Result 1 ->

```
1           manta           apple           apple-red       red         0.147
3           poma            apple           apple-red       red         0.111
5           pinas           pineapple       pinneaple-brown brown       0.890
6           gordon          apple           apple-red       red         0.135
```

So far so good, however i get 3 sellers who have red apple's with the apple-red ref.

Now this is the part that i can't resolve...

With this result, I would like to filter the duplicated apples refs ( since i want to buy from one seller ).

If there's duplicates, select the one with the seller manta.

If there's duplicates, and no one of them is seller manta, then select the one with the lowest cost per kilogram.

So after the result 1, the second query (or subquery, or if there's a way to do it all in one query i really don't know what would be the best way) expected result would be:

```
1           manta           apple           apple-red       red         0.147
5           pinas           pineapple       pinneaple-brown brown       0.890
```

Or in case manta didn't sell these it would be:

```
3           poma            apple           apple-red       red         0.111
5           pinas           pineapple       pinneaple-brown brown       0.890
```

Is it possible to do this with only one query?
Or may I somehow do a view from the result or temporal table and then execute one more query to filter the duplicates.
How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a prioritization query.

I think you want:

```
select f.*  
from fruits f
where f.seller in ('manta', 'poma', 'pinas', 'gordon') and 
      f.class in ('apple', 'pineapple') and
      f.id = (select f2.id
              from fruits f2
              where f2.seller in ('manta', 'poma', 'pinas', 'gordon') and 
                    f2.class in ('apple', 'pineapple') and
                    f2.ref = f.ref
              order by (f2.seller = 'manta') desc,  -- put manta sellers first
                       f2.price asc                 -- then order by lowest price
              limit 1
             );
```

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Can you be more specific?